# Trying to find Rx in this circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, resistors

[image]

Ra = 4 Ohms, Rb = 3 Ohms, Rc = 6 Ohms, Rd = 9 Ohms.

I'm not sure how to proceed given the nodal equation of the supernode is $$(v - 21) / 4 + v / 3 + (v + 9) / Rx$$

I believe the supernode contains the 9 Volt DC voltage supply.

**Rx can be derived from the information given here.**

Comment: Where is Rx in schematic ?

Comment: This is all of the given information.

Comment: Unless Rx is defined, we cannot help you.

Comment: By inspection, Rx = Rc || Rd.  The voltage at the + terminal of the 9V source, relative to ground, is v+9. The current flowing out of the 9V source's + terminal is (v+9)/(Rc||Rd)=(v+9)/Rx. Therefore, Rx=Rc||Rd.

Comment: @JimFischer write it as an answer.

Comment: Correct, Jim. Use your answer.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{(v - 21)}{4} +\frac{ v }{ 3} + \frac{(v + 9)}{ R_x} = 0$$

The equation is of nodal voltage form.

[image]

Applying Nodal law at Node A, since v = voltage at node A,

$$\frac{(v - 21)}{R_a} +\frac{ v }{ R_b} + \frac{(v + 9)}{ R_c||R_d}$$

Comparing it with the equation in the question,

$$\implies R_x = R_c||R_d = 6||9 = 54/15 = 3.6 \Omega$$